# How to add XX:PermSize to every run config

Tags: eclipse

Recently all my runs of my java code eclipse have been giving me permMem errors. 
I can fix this with adding

-XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M

to the dun/debug config, but I don't want to keep doing this. My eclipse config has:

> eclipse.vm=C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe eclipse.vmargs=-Xms384m
>   -Xmx768m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=384m

Answer (score 0):

You can make your VM options to be shared by new run/debug launches by adding you options to  Launching Arguments.
It is explained [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/target_shared/edit_target_arguments_tab.htm).

**Edit:**
My first answer was about plug-in development, sorry about that. You can add shared vm options by:
Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs->Select Your JRE->Edit->Add your vm arguments to *Default VM Arguments*

This adds your VM arguments to your Java application run/debug configurations.

Comment: thanks but can you tell me how to get to that dialogue in eclipse 3.8?